# Где найти правила русской орфоэпии?

Tags: орфоэпия, источники, запрос-ссылок

Уважаемые участники форума, подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли хорошие источники (справочники, пособия и т.д.), где изложены различные орфоэпические правила и нормы русского языка, какие-либо закономерности в постановке ударения в словах разных частей речи? Хотелось бы погрузиться в эту тему, но пока нахожу лишь отрывочную информацию на посредственных сайтах. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Есть Аванесов Р.И. Русское литературное произношение

Comment: Спасибо больше! Это очень полезный материал для меня. Однако меня больше интересуют справочники, дающие теоретическую информацию, — правила и закономерности постановки ударений, то есть не словарь, а именно правила, справочные материалы. Вы не могли бы подсказать что-нибудь в этом роде?

Comment: Поищите видео А.Зализняка про ударение. У него есть несколько интересных лекций. Там много про правила, закономерности и тенденции.

Answer (score 1):

Я пользуюсь справочником Т.Ивановой и Т. Черкасовой "Русская речь в эфире".

Теория неплохо изложена в пособии для студентов на этом сайте: https://studopedia.ru/7_64648_orfoepicheskie-normi.html

В конце этого пособия перечислена литература для чтения, но далеко не всё есть в Сети, многое можно видеть только в печатном варианте.